# Javascript, regex - get the numbers from the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this:

**xxx-string-string**

Where **xxx** can be number from 1 to 5 characters long. I need to select them and the first **-** character and remove them from the string. How can I do this (I am not good with regex, and I am slowly starting to loose my mind :D)?

Comment: `var nStr = str.replace(str.split("-")[0]+"-","")` if you are sure that the number is always between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
var n = '12345-string-string';
var r = n.replace(/^\d{1,5}-/, '');
//=> string-string
```

**Explanation:** `\d{1,5}-` will match digits of length 1 to 5 followed by a hyphen and `^` before it will make sure to match at the beginning of your string.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.